# USB disk shows 2 MB instead 4 GB

Tags: usb

My 4 GB USB shows 2 MB, I have read lot of answers on many site as well as *Ask Ubuntu*, tried this problem to solve from both the platforms windows XP & 7 and Ubuntu but all is vain. Someone can help me please?

Comment: Tell us what you did already.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have only one intact partition that is 2MB in size. The easiest way to solve this would be through GParted, a disk partitioning program.

You'll have to install it first and you do that by opening a terminal (you can find that in the app launcher, top left corner) and executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

When you run the first command it will ask you for your password, just type your login password (It will not show any feedback while you're typing, not even * characters).

After it has finished installing make sure that your USB stick is plugged in and run GParted from the terminal by running this command

```
sudo gparted
```

You will see something like this (Your partitions will wary, dont worry about that):
[image: Gparted window]

Pick your USB from the top righ dropdown menu, if you have only one HDD it will most likely be the second option, just look for a disk at around 8GB in size, now it should look like this (again, ignore the variations in sizes and names):

[image]

select a partition from the list and right click>delete (or just press the delete key on the keyboard). Repeat this with every partition until you have only Unallocated space listed. Select it and right click>New. A windows similar to this will pop up:

[image]

On the right side under File system select fat32, the default should be ext4, so be sure to change that, otherwise any windows system wont be able to read the usb. Leave everything else as is and hit Add. At last but not least hit the apply button on the tool bar on the top (It's the button on the right), hit accept and wait for it to finish (DO NOT REMOVE THE USB UNTIL IT'S DONE, you could damage it).

Good Luck.